# How to speed up the boot time for a MIG instances?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm running an autoscaling MIG, it often scales up and down.

I specify a startup script that pulls a docker image from artifact registry:

```
docker run us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/$APP_ID/$APP_ID:latest
```

Some of my MIGs are pulling big containers (1.5GB), but most of the containers are <150MB.

How do I get it to the minimal possible startup time?

Would it help if I would be creating a Images instead of Templates and specifying them as a bootup disk or something?

Comment: Time the various stages of startup and post those details in your question. I wrote an article that might help you figure out startup time: https://www.jhanley.com/google-compute-startup-script-total-execution-time/

Comment: @stkvtflw Did John Hanley comment help you to solve your issue?